# What does the word 「ならんとな」mean in this sentence?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

It is said by an adult man to a young man.

> おれっちのみたこと　あの子も　かなーりの盗賊のうでを持っていそうだったぜ。　まあ　あの子に負けねぇおとこには**ならんとな**。

In my understanding, the word 「ならんとな」 consists of 「ならない」, which means 'not become', and  particle 「とな」to emphasize his statement.

However, when I tried to translate the later sentence, it turned out like this.

> Well, you should not become a man who does not lose to that kid.

, which I think it looks opposite to my sense.

Comment: Related？:[ないと attached to a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/76626/%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84%e3%81%a8-attached-to-a-verb)

Comment: The first part should be みたとこ (=みたところ), not みたこと.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit of a tricky word. A proper translation would be:

> From what I've seen, he/she seems to be a pretty good bandit too. Well, I (or you)'ll have to be as good as him/her.

ならんとな is a corrupted form of "ならないと(いけない/だめだ)な".

So (if I'm understanding right) both of your ideas are (sadly) wrong.